# Simple Paths between 2 nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph

I know that myself,and many others probably stuch here,

Well,according to the **CLRS(3 edition,22.4.2)**,there is a O(n) algorithm for finding all simple paths between 2 nodes in a directed acyclic graph.
I went through similar questions,[Number of paths between two nodes in a DAG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164719/number-of-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-dag?lq=1) and [All the paths between 2 nodes in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802755/all-the-paths-between-2-nodes-in-graph),but on both occasions,no proper explanation or pseudocode is mentioned,or if it is,i doubt that is it the most efficient one (`O(n)`).

If someone could really post one exact code,or pseudocode,which settles the deal,because as i went through all those above links,i didnt really find 1 single answer which stands Tall.

It would be better if the code also handles **cyclic** graphs,i.e,**IF there is a cycle** in the graph,but **If no path** between two nodes contains the **cycle**,the number of paths SHOULD be **FINITE,else INFINITE.**

Comment: I think you misread the CLRS, would you quote exact paragraph about finding the all paths in O(n) from the book?

Comment: Saeed,I am afraid i didnt misread.It is an exercise question on page 614,22.4.2,CLRS 3 edition.!

Answer (score 7):

[Jeremiah Willcock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319906/jeremiah-willcock)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5164820/1465287) is correct but light on details. Here's the linear-time algorithm for DAGs.

```
for each node v, initialize num_paths[v] = 0
let t be the destination and set num_paths[t] = 1
for each node v in reverse topological order (sinks before sources):
    for each successor w of v:
        set num_paths[v] = num_paths[v] + num_paths[w]
let s be the origin and return num_paths[s]
```

<strike>I'm pretty sure the problem for general directed graphs is [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete), but I couldn't find anything in a couple minutes of searching except an [unsourced question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6400/approximation-for-counting-the-number-of-simple-s-t-paths-in-a-general-graph) on cstheory.</strike>

Okay, here's some pseudocode. I've integrated the contents of the previous algorithm with the topological sort and added some cycle detection logic. In case of a cycle between `s` and `t`, the values of `num_paths` may be inaccurate but will be zero-nonzero depending on whether `t` is reachable. Not every node in a cycle will have `in_cycle` set to true, but every SCC root (in the sense of Tarjan's SCC algorithm) will, which suffices to trigger the early exit if and only if there is a cycle between s and t.

```
REVISED ALGORITHM

let the origin be s
let the destination be t
for each node v, initialize
    color[v] = WHITE
    num_paths[v] = 0
    in_cycle[v] = FALSE
num_paths[t] = 1
let P be an empty stack
push (ENTER, s) onto P
while P is not empty:
    pop (op, v) from P
    if op == ENTER:
        if color[v] == WHITE:
            color[v] = GRAY
            push (LEAVE, v) onto P
            for each successor w of v:
                push (ENTER, w) onto P
        else if color[v] == GRAY:
            in_cycle[v] = TRUE
    else:  # op == LEAVE
        color[v] = BLACK
        for each successor w of v:
            set num_paths[v] = num_paths[v] + num_paths[w]
        if num_paths[v] > 0 and in_cycle[v]:
            return infinity
return num_paths[s]
```

Comment: ,Could you please suggest as on how to modify it to detect cycle,cuz in that case,numpaths would be INFINITE?

Comment: rich,thanks a lot.It works like a dream.But it doesnt handle the case when there is a cycle in graph(yeah i admit i asked bout DAG),but still if could suggest modification.!

Comment: You can detect cycles while determining the topological order - the DFS will double back on a gray node.

Comment: But that would find every cycle present in graph,even if the cycle is not NOT reachable from both,Source and sink.

Comment: BTW, I've kept WHITE/GRAY/BLACK and in_cycle separate for pedagogical reasons, but an efficient implementation could use four combined states WHITE/GRAYNOCYCLE/GRAYCYCLE/BLACK.